# CRM 2011 :LINQ query not getting executed

Tags: c#, sql, linq, dynamics-crm-2011

i implemented my first LINQ query to check for duplicate records while the user adds a new record but it is not getting fired

I am working on CRM2011 and i wrote the plugin using LINQ and registered it with Plugin Registration Tool

Below is my code

```
 if (context.Depth == 1)
        {
            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
            context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
                target =(Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
                if (target != null)
                {
                    householdname = target.GetAttributeValue<string>("mcg_HouseholdName");
                }
            }
            OrganizationServiceContext orgcontext = new OrganizationServiceContext(service);
            {
                var query = (from c in orgcontext.CreateQuery<mcg_household>()
                             where c.mcg_HouseholdName == householdname
                             select c
                            );
                List<mcg_household> householdlist = query.ToList<mcg_household>();
                if (householdlist.Count > 0)
                {
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Record Already Exists!");
                }
            }
        }
```

i think the problem is with getattribute because when i check it with some hardcoded value it runs. please tell me in what stage i should register this plugin and if there is anything wrong with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code works with hardcoded example it is probably problem with stage of execution. You have to register your plugin step in Pre-Operation stage of execution and Synchronous mode. [Check this article for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327941).

Also, check if "mcg_HouseholdName" is correct string.